# Nested Scripts Can't Find Each Other In Docker Image

Tags: linux, docker, confluent-platform, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile as such:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY confluent-5.3.0 confluent-5.3.0
COPY startup.sh startup.sh
COPY start-connector.sh start-connector.sh
RUN chmod +x startup.sh
RUN chmod +x start-connector.sh
RUN chmod +x confluent-5.3.0/bin/connect-standalone
EXPOSE 8083:8083
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
```

The entrypoint runs my startup script (of which when I run on Linux it works as expected), however, when I run my image I get the following error:

`./root/start-connector.sh: line 3: ./root/confluent-5.3.0/bin/connect-standalone: Permission denied`

So I make this script exectuable by adding the following to my Dockerfile:

`RUN chmod +x confluent-5.3.0/bin/kafka-run-class`

After rebuilding and running I now get this error:

`./confluent-5.3.0/bin/connect-standalone: exec: line 75: ./confluent-5.3.0/bin/kafka-run-class: not found`

So the file exists and is executable, but after copying the nested folder structure to the image, some nested scripts are breaking.  I have inspected the container and confirmed that all the files were copied appropriately.  Note that connect-standalone and kafka-run-class are both in the same directory.

The specific line that fails in the code snippet above is here:

```
echo "$(dirname $0)"
exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class
```

Where dirname outputs `./confluent-5.3.0/bin`

So tl;dr my script works when running on Linux.  But after creating my Docker image, some pointers in scripts I did not write seem to be mismatched.  After double checking the file structure and echoing variables, everything seems to be set properly and I cannot figure out why the nested scripts can't find each other.

Answer (score 0):

So the nested scripts were running bash which isn't pre-installed on Alpine.  In the case someone else runs into this issue, just add bash to your Dockerfile:

`RUN apk --no-cache add bash`

or use something other than Alpine.